# iOS5 > app freezes when Editing Changed function is fired on UITextField

Tags: ios5, ibaction

I am firing the following function on "Editing Changed" on a UITextField. The purpose is to format the number as the user types in. 
It is working fine on iOS6+ but the app freezes on iOS5 just as the user types the first character in that field. Can somebody help to find out what might be the issue with this 3 line function. 
It freezes on the third line where NSNumberFormatter is being used.

```
-(IBAction)formatNumber:(UITextField*)sender
{
if(sender.text!=NULL)
{
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
NSString *currentVal=[[sender.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

sender.text=[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[currentVal intValue]]
                                 numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that event UIControlEventEditingChanged is called every time something is changed in the sender.

By setting new text:

```
sender.text=[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[currentVal intValue]]
                             numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

you are actually sending event UIControlEventEditingChanged again and again, causing endless recursion.

Comment: That's the point! Thanks alot.
They have surely done some change in that in iOS6, so it does not appear there.